# How to change password of logged in user in vuejs and laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a laravel+vuejs project. I want to change the password of logged in user but does not know how to change the password with api token also how to get user id in vue component. Please tell me how to change the password of logged in user. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using the API token then you have the token which includes the user information. I don't know what is the issue. The second thing you should share the code.

Comment: ok thanks next time I will share the code.

Comment: I hope the token will help you to get the user info and  change the password.